# Get content of specific page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

at the moment I am querying out all pages that I have in WordPress and am displaying them on a page. Like this:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page'));
while(have_posts()) 
{ 
$this_page = the_post();
echo the_content();
} 
?>
```

The question is, how can I do the same thing but just for one specific post? As a side note, if I need to use id's of pages where can I find them, as at the moment I don't see what id page has in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );//al items from my-category-slug
while(have_posts()) 
{ 
  $this_page = the_post();
  echo the_content();
}
```

Comment: can you explain what 'my-category-slug' does? So would this filter posts by category? Is it possible to do something similar, but to filter posts by title of the page?

Comment: The “slug” is the URL-friendly version of the name. It is usually all lowercase and contains only letters, numbers, and hyphens.
i dont know if possible your third answer :(

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the page on query_posts in the wordpress codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts .

Adjust arguments accordingly. For example, to query a post with a specific id:

```
query_posts( 'p=5' );
```

Comment: Tried it out, and had a quick look at link you provided, thank you very helpful, but it doesn't seem to work, I assume it is because it uses posts where as I use pages, is there a way to adjust this to use pages instead of posts?

Comment: if you want to get a specific post, you can use get_post($post_id) . for example, for post 5:    

    $mypost=get_post(5);
    echo $myPost->post_content

Comment: alternatively, try to use at WP_Query or you can make a full sql query to the database with the wpdb object: $wpdb->get_results($query)

Comment: yeh I see what you mean there, but the thing is I don't need to get a specific post, I need to get a specific page, would something like get_page(5); work?

Comment: ah ok, now that's different. You wrote you wanted a specific post, that is why I was trying to get... wp_query should do the job with the post_type set to page or to any like this:

    $args = array(
       'p' => $postID,
       'post_type' => 'any'
     );
    $result = new WP_Query($args);